# How to catch the decompress IOError?

Tags: haskell, gzip

I wrote this code snippet to read a file that may be compressed:

```
import Codec.Compression.GZip
import IO -- using IO.try

read file = do
  let f = L.readFile file
  let c = fmap decompress $ f

  unzipped <- try c

  case unzipped of
    Right b -> return b
    Left  _ -> f
```

It compiles just fine, but it seems that this is no valid way to handle uncompressed files. Running the code on a compressed file works nice, but a uncompressed file fails with an exception:

```
*** Exception: Codec.Compression.Zlib: incorrect header check
```

Any idea on how to make this possible?

Comment: `IO.try` is deprecated... what about  Control.Exception.try`? http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception.html#v:try

Comment: More to the point, `IO.try` specifically does not catch exceptions from pure code, while `Control.Exception.try` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import Codec.Compression.Zlib.Internal. Note in particular the section titled [“Low-level API to get explicit error reports”](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/zlib/0.5.3.3/doc/html/Codec-Compression-Zlib-Internal.html#g:4).

You will want to use something like this (note untested):

```
import qualified Codec.Compression.Zlib.Internal as Z
import Control.Arrow (right)

decompressWithoutExceptions :: L.ByteString -> Either Z.DecompressError L.ByteString
decompressWithoutExceptions = finalise
                            . Z.foldDecompressStream cons nil err
                            . Z.decompressWithErrors Z.gzipFormat Z.defaultDecompressParams
  where err errorCode errorString = Left errorCode
        nil = Right []
        cons chunk = right (chunk :)
        finalise = right L.fromChunks
```

(I presume you have imported Data.ByteString.Lazy qualified as L.)

Comment: Never mind that, does it work?! (Which bits do you not understand? `decompressWithErrors` and `foldDecompressStream`, etc are explained (perhaps not clearly enough?) in the documentation I linked to.)

Comment: Where does this finalise method come from? I didn't find it via hayoo.

Comment: `finalise` is defined in the last line. It's purpose is to convert the result from type `Either Z.DecompressError [Data.ByteString.ByteString]` to `Either Z.DecompressError L.ByteString` (i.e. converting the "success" type from a list of strict bytestrings to a single lazy bytestring).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [spoon](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon), which will allow you to get `Nothing` if an exception was thrown.